# What are nested parameters in http?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, http

In the [Laravel Docs on validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) they speak of 'nested parameters':

> If your HTTP request contains "nested" parameters, you may specify them in your validation rules using "dot" syntax:
>
> ```
> $this->validate($request, [
>     'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
>     'author.name' => 'required',
>     'author.description' => 'required',
> ]);
> ```

What would the HTML look like for this nesting? I googled around, and found nothing except things about form nesting. Also, the `"dot" syntax`, is this specific to Laravel?

Comment: This is nothing magic. Just use `name="author.name"`. :-)

Comment: Also, the `.` syntax for accessing variables is a feature of Laravel, used for accessing array values (such as above) or accessing file/folder hierarchy, such as `return view("folder.file")`

Comment: Them mentioning it kinda confuses me, and made me think it's some special thing. Is there a way to semantically nest things in forms in HTML though, bar comments? It would make code more readable, while having no impact on rendering.

Comment: @TimLewis true, thanks for mentioning that. That's what actually made me think it was this special thing

Comment: @arkascha or Tim Lewis, could either one of you combine both your comments into an answer, so I can mark it as the answer? Otherwise I'm doing it in a week or so ;)

Comment: @DaJF Don't feel bad buddy, it blew my mind too, I started searching to see what they were, your question was totally valid. I wanted to see what the HTML syntax would look like, while I was guessing it was either an array syntax <input name="something['nested']"> or just a dot in the name "something.name" but the laravel doc was vague, and you never know, at some point a new version of HTTP is going to introduce new things.

Answer (score 5):

The dot notation is for easily accessing array elements, and making their selectors more "fluent".

Validating `author.name` would be the equivalent of having checking the value of the input `<input type="text" name="author[name]" />`.

This makes having multi model forms or grouping related data much nicer =). You can then get all the data for that thing by doing something like `$request->request('author');` and that would give you the collection/array of all the values submitted with `author[*]`. Laravel also uses it with its config accessors - so `config.setting.parameter` is the equivalent of `config[setting][parameter]`

Basically makes working with array data easier.

See https://github.com/glopezdetorre/dot-notation-access for some examples!

Answer (score -1):

The Html form will look like  Nothing More